# Monitor Postgres Database with Python

Tags: python, postgresql

I have an ERP and that will provide me access to some data I need to integrate with another system.
My question is, how do I get "Listening" monitoring the database and whenever there is a change I can get it to send to the other system.

Comment: Google "postgresql replication" and "postgresql triggers" depending on how you want this to work. There are many many scenarios.

...
Or you could just tail the postgresql query log, but that's horrible.

Comment: @AlexanderMP
But are these the only formats?
because getting the Log file is going to be torture ...

Comment: That's why I said that it's horrible.
What you want is basically master-slave replication.

Comment: @AlexanderMP 
Exactly, but I wanted to do it in a more practical way.
Example: in a format similar to the Twitter API